# Fetching data from web page

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch the publication date corresponding to each patent number.

Here is the Excel sheet:

[image]

The database is espacenet.com

Here's the link for the first patent you see in the Excel sheet:
http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?compact=false&PN=US7055777B2&ST=advanced&locale=en_EP&DB=EPODOC

Under the "Publication Info" header, I need to get the date after matching the patent number with the one in the Excel sheet.

Here's the code:

```
Sub tryextraction()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim sdd As String
Dim tdd() As String
Dim num0 As Integer
Dim num1 As Integer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

ie.Visible = True

num1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For num0 = 2 To num1
     ie.navigate "http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?compact=false&PN=" & Range("A" & num0) & "&ST=advanced&locale=en_EP&DB=EPODOC"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set doc = ie.document
    sdd = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText)
    tdd() = Split(sdd, vbLf)
    j = UBound(tdd)

    For i = 0 To j
        If InStr(tdd(i), "(") <> 0 Then
            tdd(i) = Replace(tdd(i), " ", "")
            tdd(i) = Replace(tdd(i), "(", "")
            tdd(i) = Replace(tdd(i), ")", "")

            If tdd(i) = Range("A" & num0).Value Then
                Range("B" & num0).Value = tdd(i + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next num0
ie.Quit

End Sub
```

The code is not giving any error. The column "Publication Date" remains blank after the code finishes running.

The html tag which contains the publication info has been taken correctly.

Comment: To anyone else reproducing this code I had to make the following changes:  Dim ie As Object, Dim doc As Object, Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"), and READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore You can also just add references to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to use the code as is.

Comment: Thanks @Portland.  I knew there was missing references, but I'm not awake enough yet to remember which ones or where to assign them in VBA.

Comment: @Tushar, it would benefit you to get to know your debugger.  I didn't figure this out by looking at the code or the source data, I ran it through the debugger and added watches for both sides of the If test that always failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some trailing white space characters after the ID you are searching for in the document so `tdd(i) = Range("A" & num0).Value` never evaluates to true.  It's not just a space, so a simple `Trim(tdd(i)) = Range("A" & num0).Value` call does not help.  Try instead `InStr(tdd(i), Range("A" & num0).Value)`  If that is not good enough, you'll have to specifically remove CRLF from the end of the string before doing the compare.

Comment: +1 You beat me by a minute :-)  `If InStr(tdd(i), Range("A" & num0).Value) Then` is a good answer.

Comment: You could find a better solution that does a real trim.  :)

Comment: My solution will fail if searching for ABC when ABCD is in the list being searched.  The original code doesn't even have a break to get out of the loop when the first successful match is found, so alphabetic ordering wouldn't resolve that.

Comment: It appears it will always be the last character so how about stripping it off like this: `tdd(i) = Left(tdd(i), Len(tdd(i)) - 1)` right before the If statement.

Comment: Working great. Thank you so much. I am loving coding

Comment: is CRLF one character or two?

Comment: Just one, I tested it to be sure.

Comment: Post it as a solution then?

Answer (score 0):

There are often multiple publication dates under the publication info header.

Example:

[image: Example]

---

The following script obtains all of these and the preceeding line (so you have the associated publication along with date).

It loops from row 2 of the `Activesheet`, to the last populated row, picking up the `Publication Numbers` from column A and writing out the results starting from column B. Depending on how many dates there are, the data will extend across multiple columns from B.

---

**Regex:**

A regex of `^(.*)\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` is used to retrieve the date pattern and the preceeding line i.e. The publication identifier and the date. <sub>[Try it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUQfC.png)</sub>

[image: Regex matches]

---

**Example output:**

[image: Example output]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As New HTMLDocument, url As String, pubInfo As Object
    Dim loopRange As Range, iRow As Range, counter As Long
    'example US7055777B2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set loopRange = Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        counter = 2                              '<== start from row 2
        For Each iRow In loopRange
            If Not IsEmpty(iRow) Then
                url = "https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?compact=false&PN=" & iRow.Value & "&ST=advanced&locale=en_EP&DB=EPODOC"
                .navigate url

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Set html = .document
                Do
                    DoEvents
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set pubInfo = html.querySelector(".publicationInfoColumn")
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Loop While pubInfo Is Nothing

                Dim tempArr()
                tempArr = GetDateAndPatent(pubInfo.innerText, "^(.*)\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}") '"(?m)^(.*)\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" '<==This is not supported

                With ActiveSheet
                    .Cells(counter, 2).Resize(1, UBound(tempArr) + 1) = tempArr
                End With
            End If
            counter = counter + 1
        Next iRow
        .Quit                                    '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetDateAndPatent(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object, s As String, arrMatches(), i As Long

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                ReDim Preserve arrMatches(i)
                arrMatches(i) = iMatch.Value
                i = i + 1
            Next iMatch
        End If
    End With
    GetDateAndPatent = arrMatches
End Function
```